# CSS different delays for different properties

Tags: html, css, angularjs

So I have a div with an image on it. On click the image expands to a larger size; height and width are transitioned. I would like to expand the height first, then the width. I am wondering, is there a way to do this with CSS only?

My code so far:

CSS:

```
.resize {
  background-image: url('http://www.purosoftware.com/escritorio-fondo-de-pantalla/imagenes/03-fondo-de-pantalla-playa-en-alta-definicion-hd-resolucion-1920x1200-01.jpeg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: height 1000ms ease; // transition height right away
  transition: width 1000ms 500ms ease; // transition width with delay
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.resize.larger {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

HTML (with Angularjs markup)

```
<!-- on click, apply 'larger' class, then remove larger class on second click -->
<div class='resize' ng-init="clicked = false"
     ng-class="{'larger': clicked}" ng-click="clicked =! clicked">

</div>
```

The second issue I'm having with this is I would like to switch the delays for height and width, meaning i would like to transition width first, then height.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/97V80ckSypkLJPLTT2UW?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare multiple transitions, but do it separating with a comma `,` not setting again the transition because it overrides the previous one:

```
.resize {
      transition: width 1s ease,
                  height 1s .5s ease;
}
```

Check the snippet below.

```css
.resize {
  background-image: url('http://www.purosoftware.com/escritorio-fondo-de-pantalla/imagenes/03-fondo-de-pantalla-playa-en-alta-definicion-hd-resolucion-1920x1200-01.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: width 1s ease, height 1s .5s ease;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.resize:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
```

```html
<div class="resize"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, any advice on how to switch the delay between height and width? (meaning: for the opening (first click) I would like to delay height, but for closing (second click) I would like to delay width instead.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon I don't know about angular yet, but mi tought with jquery will be when change the class maybe I'm gonna try on your plunker.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon check this just on the class large add the transition property changing the order or values http://plnkr.co/edit/QBpoD5Gtg3vko9HoNqUw?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can comma separate them

```
{
transition: 
height 1000ms ease,
width 1000ms 500ms ease; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any advice on how to switch the delay between height and width? (meaning: for the opening (first click) I would like to delay height, but for closing (second click) I would like to delay width instead.

Comment: `transition` is shorthand. Just separate it out into each property and comma separate each 'sub-property'.

Comment: I'm not much of an expert on CSS, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the answers already provided, the [proper syntax](http://designshack.net/articles/css/create-stunning-effects-with-css-transition-delays/) for writing transition properties is:

```
transition: [property] [duration] <timing function> <delay>;
```

Just write:

```
transition: height 1s linear, width 1s ease 1s;
```

where the transition for the `width` would be called right after the transition for the `height` finishes.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/767CogVGYUlcPWlLC7uy?p=preview

Comment: Fixed the bug, but just follow [this source](http://designshack.net/articles/css/create-stunning-effects-with-css-transition-delays/).